# Prevent an aws account from going into using on-demand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have a purchased a fleet of reserved instances in our AWS account which we use for out EMR cluster. Multiple developers create EMR clusters pulling reserved instances out of our AWS account and if it goes over the limit it goes into on-demand mode which makes it very expensive. We want to able to prevent this from happening. Anyway we can query our AWS account to make sure that no on-demand instances are being used?

Comment: Note that RIs aren't physical instances. They're a billing discount applied to the use of on-demand Instances in your account. So, a solution that counts running instances (or triggers on a RunInstances API) and compares the count of currently-running instances to your reservation might work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'prevent' usage of non-Reserved Instances.

Reserved Instances are a **billing discount** calculated when charges are applied. There is no facility to 'block' the use of serves that are not covered by Reserved Instance discounts.

There are some [Reserved Instance (RI) Reporting](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/reserved-instance-reporting/) capabilities in the Cost and Usage Report that can indicate whether you are taking advantage of all RIs (eg not using them at night).

I recall hearing that Netflix had written a utility to encourage Amazon EMR users to use an existing cluster or to launch a cluster using "unused RIs". The system would **launch the clusters on behalf of users**, rather than allowing users to directly launch clusters, so there was an opportunity to check utilization or prompt for confirmation before launching the resources. You could write something similar, that checks for existing EC2 usage and launches the cluster on the user's behalf if there is spare RI capacity.